# How to test for stack overflow on an ATtiny85 using an emulator?

Tags: arduino, debugging, ram, attiny85, stack

I am developing a hobby project using the Arduino IDE and an USBasp programmer to upload my code to the ATtiny85. After programming, I remove the chip from the programmer socket and put it into the target device (two buttons and an I2C 128x32 OLED display.)

When compiling in the Arduino IDE, the output says I have 89 bytes of RAM memory left for local variables. As I understand it, this memory shrinks when functions are called and local variables are declared. I can't say if a crash condition can occur.

Is there a simple way to emulate program execution and watch in real time how much memory is left?

**EDIT 1**

I tried using [this approach](https://shop.wickeddevice.com/2012/10/05/avr-stack-overflow/) with PRINT_STACK_SPACE changed to:

```
#define PRINT_STACK_SPACE do {   itoa(StackCount(), buffer, 10); oled.setFont(FONT6X8);  oled.setCursor(0, 0);  oled.print(buffer);  oled.setFont(FONT8X16); } while(0)
```

It seems that `StackCount()` always returns zero. I put `PRINT_STACK_SPACE` at the beginning of the execution in setup, after the OLED display is initialized, and in some places in `loop()`; it always shows zero.

I don't understand the symbols used in StackPaint - maybe something has to be adapted to the ATtiny85 and the Arduino IDE?

**EDIT 2**

OK, for testing I removed everything else except OLED initialization and stackpainting, the code:

```
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/power.h>    
#include <avr/wdt.h> 
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <TinyWireM.h>
#include <Tiny4kOLED.h>

#define POWER_PIN 1
#define BUTTON1_PIN 3
#define BUTTON2_PIN 4

char buffer[14];

extern uint8_t _end;
extern uint8_t __stack;

#define STACK_CANARY  0xfe
void StackPaint(void) __attribute__ ((naked)) __attribute__ ((section (".init1")));

void StackPaint(void)
{
  #if 0
  uint8_t *p = &_end;

  while(p <= &__stack)
  {
  *p = STACK_CANARY;
  p++; 
  }
  #else
  __asm volatile ("    ldi r30,lo8(_end)n"
  "    ldi r31,hi8(_end)n"
  "    ldi r24,lo8(0xfe)n" /* STACK_CANARY = 0xfe */
  "    ldi r25,hi8(__stack)n"
  "    rjmp .cmpn"
  ".loop:n"
  "    st Z+,r24n"
  ".cmp:n"
  "    cpi r30,lo8(__stack)n"
  "    cpc r31,r25n"
  "    brlo .loopn"
  "    breq .loop"::);
  #endif
  }

uint16_t StackCount(void)
{
  const uint8_t *p = &_end;
  uint16_t       c = 0;

  while(*p == STACK_CANARY && p <= &__stack)
  {    
    p++;
    c++;
  }

  return c;
}

#define PRINT_STACK_SPACE do{   itoa(StackCount(), buffer, 10);    oled.setFont(FONT6X8); oled.setCursor(0, 0); oled.print(buffer); oled.setFont(FONT8X16); } while(0)


void setup() {
  pinMode(0, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(5, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(POWER_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTON1_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(BUTTON2_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);

  digitalWrite(POWER_PIN, HIGH);
  delay(10);
  oled.begin(128, 32, sizeof(tiny4koled_init_128x32br), tiny4koled_init_128x32br);
  oled.setFont(FONT8X16);
  oled.clear();
  oled.on();
  delay(10);
  PRINT_STACK_SPACE;
}

void loop() {
  PRINT_STACK_SPACE;
  delay(10);

}
```

The compiler says "Global variables use 108 bytes (21%) of dynamic memory, leaving 404 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 512 bytes." but the only displayed number is still zero.

Answer (score 1):

Simple is a relative term. One technique I have used in the past is stack painting. The basic idea is you fill RAM with a known / repeating pattern. You can, in this way, know the deepest level to which RAM has been written by looking for the first instance of the pattern, and assuming that it wasn't written by  your code after initialization.

I wrote a pretty thorough blog post about this topic many years ago, and I don't think the state of the art has changed much since

https://shop.wickeddevice.com/2012/10/05/avr-stack-overflow/

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how to read  RAM at runtime? Especially if the microcontroller is put in another device? Or are you talking about emulation?

Comment: You just use a pointer and walk through the memory, C is very permissive in this regard. Take a look at the blog post, there is code shown there, see StackCount() and StackPaint()

Comment: I used the code from the blog post, changed serial output to oled display. I try to display from time to time size of available stack on OLED since i don't have serial connected. Code compiles and I understand the principle, but it seems that StackCount() always returns zero...

Comment: It is possible that the stack is full from the beginning, and some bytes are overwritten and the code works "by chance". But i put modified PRINT_STACK_SPACE macro in setup just after oled is initialized and it shows zero from the beginning. I don't uderstand why macro uses do while (0), what are extern _end and __stack symbols and why StackPaint containd #if 0 preprocessor that never enters. Could you explain? I'll update my question, mayby for attiny85 some code change is required? I use latest arduino IDE and uspASB to upload.

Comment: Yes, that's not a great sign... Try it with an empty sketch and output to the serial port instead and see what it says

Comment: I did exactly that and still it shows zero, so I think that there is sth wrong with my code. I updated my question above to include code.

Comment: You are still including OLED code, it might be overflowing with just that. Try the same code on an Arduino UNO...